# Qual é o motivo de poder selecionar apenas 3 tags no filtro de votos para fechar?

Tags: suporte, tags, fechamento, filas-de-análise

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Geralmente, só analiso votos de tags em que possuo algum conhecimento. Seria melhor se eu pudesse selecionar mais tags, assim não precisaria ficar trocando as tags quando visito a fila de análise.

Comment: Não é só pular quando for de um assunto que não domine ou não tenha conhecimento? Geralmente eu só pulo quando não domino o tema.

Comment: Até é, mas isso leva bem mais tempo do que já ter filtrado.

Comment: Não sei. O que encontrei até o momento foi uma solicitação de nova feature postada no metão pedindo tornar possível que mais tags pudessem ser selecionadas de uma só vez: [Allow to filter for more than three tags in the close votes review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220924/229289) Infelizmente ela não recebeu muita atenção, não sei se não tem outra FR igual porém mais votada. Uma gambi que se pode fazer por ora é colocar as tags no link da fila de análises por exemplo assim: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=java,c,r,php,delphi

Comment: Legal, se dá para filtrar pela URL já resolve o problema! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Math acho que seu comentário ficaria bem como resposta, acredito que muitos(inclusive eu) desconheciam essa alternativa :)

Comment: Eu nem sabia que dava para fazer isso ahahahah

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essa limitação está na UI do site, é possível selecionar várias tags escrevendo-as diretamente na URL da fila de votos de fechamento, por exemplo assim:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=java,c,r,php,delphi

Encontrei essa resposta ao achar uma solicitação de nova feature postada no metão: [Allow to filter for more than three tags in the close votes review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220924/229289).

Infelizmente ela não recebeu muita atenção e acho não estão preocupados em melhorar a UI para permitir mais tags no filtro. Por ora a solução é editar a URL na mão, e salvá-la nos favoritos, por exemplo.

#### Bônus

Também é possível filtrar as perguntas por "Motivos de fechamento", usando o filtro `filter-closereason`. Exemplo:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=c&filter-closereason=duplicate

Os possíveis motivos de fechamento são:

- filter-closereason=duplicate
- filter-closereason=offtopic
- filter-closereason=unclear
- filter-closereason=toobroad
- filter-closereason=opinionbased

Post original: [Allow direct linking to a filtered /review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209777/229289)